# Leaflet Minimap width base layer change

Tags: leaflet

I have implemented a minimap and I'm trying to hang a type click event to change the base layer. Like google maps.

But it does not work. This is my code:

```
_onBaselayerChanger: function (e) {
  var currentBaselayer = [];
  this._map.eachLayer(function(layer) {
      if( layer instanceof L.TileLayer )
          currentBaselayer.push(layer);
  });
  this._map.removeLayer(currentBaselayer[0]);
  this._map.addLayer(this._layer);
}
```

Is there a plugin or something to help me?

Answer (score 1):

There is not enough code in your post to get it testing (maybe you can create a simple fiddle?). However, in case you didn't run into those links before, here are examples that may be helpful for you to implement the action under your minimap click event:

http://leafletjs.com/examples/layers-control/

https://leaflet-extras.github.io/leaflet-providers/preview/

To find minimap plugin google the names: L.Control.Layers.Minimap.js or Norkart/Leaflet-MiniMap.

Comment: yep, L.Control.Layers.Minimap.js is the excellent base! Thx